# SoapUI testcases reports are not correctly generating

Tags: testing, soapui

I am using `SoapUI v5.2.1` for testing `OSB Services`.

```
    LoginTestCase
         |
         |__TestSuite
              |
              |__TestCase1
              |      |
              |      |__Success Test Step
              |     
              |__TestCase2
                     |
                     |__Failure Test Step
```

I have configured everything as the directory I have mentioned.
it giving the `Failure Test output` as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>XYZ-001: input is wrong</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
               <con:errorCode>XYZ-001</con:errorCode>
               <con:reason>input is wrong</con:reason>
               <con:location>
                  <con:node>PipelinePairNode1</con:node>
                  <con:pipeline>PipelinePairNode1_response</con:pipeline>
                  <con:stage>stage1</con:stage>
                  <con:path>response-pipeline</con:path>
               </con:location>
            </con:fault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this is a failed result, so it should be under the failed category.
But when I am running it from test runner it is giving:

```
SoapUI 5.2.1 TestCaseRunner Summary
-----------------------------
Time Taken: 430ms
Total TestSuites: 1
Total TestCases: 2 (0 failed)
Total TestSteps: 2
Total Request Assertions: 0
Total Failed Assertions: 0
Total Exported Results: 2
```

I need to know why is it giving the 0 failed instead of 1 test case being failed?

Comment: How does test case know? Have you added any test assertions?

Comment: @Rao can you explain about assertions?

Comment: Please go thru the documentation - https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html

Comment: And obviously, the negative tests should also pass with appropriate assertions.